# What to do with chatbot based questions?

Tags: discussion

I am starting to see many questions based on chatbot output, not just on this SE site. No doubt chatbots will at some point become scarily accurate, but at the moment their output is usually well formulated gibberish - an accurate answer is usually luck.

I do not mind clearing up inaccuracies in the least, if someone asks something based on content from a friend, a news outlet or other valid source. I do think that we may want to consider making chatbot based questions off-topic.

I'll add a couple of answers below, upvote which one you like.

Comment: For reference, such practice is [banned on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831).

Comment: That's good to know, what's the process for getting rid of these then?

Comment: I think we make the process. "banned on SO" means that they are explicitly off-topic on SO, on top of any other OT category they have.

Comment: If the community here wants to ban chatbot-based questions here, it will be shown by the voting on the answers here. Stack Overflow policies do not automatically carry over to other sites.

Comment: @Someone did I suggest anything that contradicts what you said?

Comment: @Federico that message was for the OP, not you.

Answer (score 7):

**Make chatbot questions off-topic**

The unreliability of chatbots makes questions based on their output low quality and often leads to bad answers. The existing off-topic categories do not cover these types of questions, so bad questions are being left on the site.

Answer (score 4):

**Let the existing off-topic categories filter these questions**

If it ain't broke don't fix it, and I don't think it's broke.